# Strange Behaviour While Connecting to Database using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPriviledges

Tags: 2013, runwithelevatedprivileges

I am a beginner in Sharepoint.

I have a stored procedured which needs to be executed when the user clicks on a button on the sharepoint page.
The `Click` event is firing as expected but I get an error saying "NT Authority\Anonymous Login` does not have the required permission.
Below is the code for calling the SP

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
{
    //Impersonate using Windows token
    using (WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = SPSecurityContext.GetWindowsIdentity().Impersonate())
    {

        _connectionString = @"Data Source=MyServer\USERDATA;initial catalog=MyDBName;integrated security=True";
        ExecuteSP();
    }
});

private void ExecuteSP()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MySPName", con);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("parameter", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

It fails at `con.Open()`

I know 100% for sure that the `ctx` does get the `Context` of the user who has logged in my application but somehow it fails while connecting to the DataBase.

This code runs perfectly on my Dev environment but fails on the testing system.

I have tried moving the entire code within `RunWithElevatedPriviledges` but still no luck :(

Any help/ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Go to you IIS Manager navigate to IIS -> Authentication and check if you have enabled these options:

- Anonymous Authentication
- Basic Authentication
- **ASP.NET Impersonation**

Comment: I checked my dev environment and only Anonymous Authentication is enabled and it works there.

Comment: Then I would suggest following these steps [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/taraj/archive/2009/01/29/checklist-for-double-hop-issues-iis-and-sql-server.aspx) to make sure you don't run into double hop issue (your IIS not propagating credentials from client to SQL Server) I suppose on your dev you have allinone Environment so this issue does not occurs, whereas prod envs are on two separate machines